# Link aggregation on ESXi: can one TCP/IP stream in a guest VM use more than one link's banwidth?

Tags: vmware-esxi, load-balancing

I have VMWare ESXi 5.1 host with several gigabit links, connected to a LACP and 802.3ad-capable switch, in a static LACP mode on a switch, with "IP hash" load balancing mode in ESXi. I'm currently using vSphere standard switch.

It seems like while load balancing works ok for multiple TCP/IP streams to/from guest VMs, no single stream can utilize more than one link (e.g. 1Gbps), due to IP hash load balancing. And this is of course the only load balancing mode that supports LACP on ESXi.

Is there anything I can do to allow one TCP/IP stream to/from guest VM to utilize several gigabit links at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't have any recourse other than expanding to a higher bandwidth (10GbE) connection.

What are you trying to do that requires multiple Gigabit bandwidth?

I *do* use LACP with distributed vSwitches now on vSphere Enterprise Plus systems. It works. But the benefits can be seen most with storage and vMotion traffic. Not individual VM connections to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry; none of ESXi's available load balancing mechanisms allow for a single TCP connection to be spread among multiple physical NICs at the same time.